# How to use this react component efficiently?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my react application, I create this CreateText component, which is used to write a post or comment on a post. This is the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Header, TextAreaFieldGroup, Button, Spinner } from '../UI'; 

const CreateText = props => {
   const { createPostData, textCreating, onInputChange, onCreateText } = props;

   const setButtonText = () => {
      let content = <Header Tag='span' text={createPostData.buttonText} />;

      if (textCreating) 
         content = <Spinner width={20} height={20} borderWidth={4} borderTopWidth={4} />;

      return content;
   }

   return (
      <div className="post-form mb-3">
         <div className="card card-info">             
            <div className="card-header bg-info text-white">
               {createPostData.header}
            </div>

            <div className="card-body">
               <form onSubmit={onCreateText}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                     <TextAreaFieldGroup 
                        placeholder={createPostData.placeholder}
                        name={createPostData.name}
                        value={createPostData.text}
                        error={createPostData.error}
                        onChange={onInputChange}
                     />
                  </div>

                  <Button
                     type='submit'
                     className='btn btn-dark col-md-2'
                     disabled={textCreating}
                  >
                     {setButtonText()}
                  </Button>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   );
}

CreateText.propTypes = {
   createPostData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   onInputChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
   onCreateText: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default CreateText;
```

I didn't use a local state for this component. I used onInputChange() prop and implemented on the 2 parent components which I had used this component. My question is, what is the best way to implement this component? Having a state inside the component and use onChange() inside the component? Or pass it as a prop and implement in the parent component?  Everywhere I used the approach that I have shown here. Which is the better approach?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you use the onchange state to component itself instead of the parent. The reason being everytime you change the state of this child component the parent component will rerender as the state is being set there.  Since you have a button you can call the parents function inside the button's onClick function. This way the parent will only be rerendered if the button is clicked instead of each keystroke. I also noticed that your code does not have an onClick function to the Button.

Comment: read about [Presentational vs Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your verification for `TextAreaFieldGroup` is complex, your solution is good in this case. Because `TextAreaFieldGroup` receive `createPostData` from it parents. 
If your verification is simple, just keep `value` on component's state and verify within component.

I just wondering why your form just has only one text field? If your form has more than one field, the best practice is using [render-props pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)